# didScroll for NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I'm newbie in macOS development. What I want is to track contentOffset of `NSCollectionView`. In iOS `UICollectionViewDelegate` inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate` and I can easily implement `scrollViewDidScroll` but in macOS can't find anything like this. `collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, willDisplay item` is not appropriate for my situation. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is good guide, hope help  - https://www.raywenderlich.com/783-nscollectionview-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found out how to track `contentOffset` but I've resolved my problem. In `NSCollectionView` there is very interesting property

```
var prefetchDataSource: NSCollectionViewPrefetching?
```

which has method:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

This method notifies your 'prefetchDataSource' that items at the specified 'indexPaths' are likely to be instantiated and displayed soon.
Hope this will be helpful for someone!